# Django-ORM: Illustrate a precise query for the situation

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-orm

I have 4 models in my project. Which are :

```
class Company(Group):

address_1 = models.CharField(max_length = 300, blank = True, null = True)
web_site = models.URLField(blank = True, null = True)
office_number = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True, null = True)


class Person(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User)
company = models.ForeignKey(Company)


class Project(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
person = models.ManyToManyField(User, through = 'UserProject')


class UserProject(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User)
project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
is_owner = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

In a view I would want to get

1. All the projects related to the request.user
2. The companies that are working on those projects
3. and the employees of those companies

I have tried writing some code but the queries are not precise. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have pondered and used some of the solutions enlisted above, but nothing was exact to what I was looking for. For me the following piece of code works well

```
            projects = Project.objects.filter(person = request.user)

            user_projects = UserProject.objects.filter(project__in = projects)

            for user_project in user_projects:
                person = user_project.user.get_profile()
                company.append(person.company)
                people.append(person)

            company = set(company)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. All projects related to request.user is easy, of course:

   ```
   Project.objects.filter(person=request.user)
   ```
2. The companies working on those projects necessarily requires you to loop through the projects:

   ```
   for p in projects:
       p.company_set.all()
   ```
3. You have no relationship between `User` and `Company`, or any other foreign key on `Company` for that matter, so I have no idea where the concept of "employee" comes from or how to get that.

Since, this is pretty basic stuff, I'm assuming your issue is with the fact 1*N queries that are generated. In the current version of Django (1.3.1), there's no way to optimize this futher. In Django 1.4, there's `prefetch_related` that will allow you to select all the companies (and employees) with the `Projects`. However, it still requires a unique query for each relationship, so 3 total to get projects, companies, and employees. It works like this:

```
Project.objects.filter(person=request.user).prefetch_related('company')
```

In the mean time, I've had some success with using [django-batch-select](https://github.com/lilspikey/django-batch-select), which basically tries to emulate the behavior of `prefetch_related`.

Comment: Part 2 can be done without a forloop (and thus the extra DB hits it creates)...

companies = Company.objects.filter(project__in=projects)

Comment: My answer assumes the OP actually wants to keep the association between a project and its companies. Yes, that will get all the companies involved in any of the projects, but you lose the ability to divvy them out by project without regrouping them in some way after the fact.

Comment: Regrouping them in Python would save on DB calls (1 query vs 1 per company). Depends what's important to the OP's particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

## OK some bugs in your models:

- Project has a M2M on User through UserProject, which is fine, except I think you mean for it to have a M2M on Person which has a FK to User
- Secondly, you haven't set up any relations to Company. there is no way to do item 2 on your list until that bug is fixed.
- Why is Company extending Group? I must be missing something.
- There is no Employee model

Example:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length = 300, blank = True, null = True)
    web_site = models.URLField(blank = True, null = True)
    office_number = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True, null = True)


class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    company = models.ForeignKey(User)


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    employees = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, through = 'EmployeeProject')
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company)


class EmployeeProject(models.Model):

    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    is_owner = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

and in the view

```
# all of the projects for a user (assuming employee field is supposed to M2M to the Employee model
projects = Project.objects.filter(employees__user=request.user)
for project in projects :
    # assuming that there was some connection between project and company (there isnt currently, see me list of bugs with your models)
    for company in project.companies_set.all() :
        # There is no employee model, but if there was
        employees = company.employees_set.all()
```